# Web Api call not reaching action?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have my WebApiConfig setup like this:

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I have registered the route in Global.asax as follows:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
```

My Web api controller class looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/upload")]
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public string Upload()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I'm making call to the Web Api action in fiddler as shown in the image below:

[image]

I'm getting 404 Not Found not found error when I send the request. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it Cross origin request error?

Comment: No. The request is made to the same domain the IIS server is running.

Comment: Are you running an instance of the service while making the call?

Comment: Yes the service is running in Debug mode while I'm making the call

Comment: Are you calling your service from asp.net mvc?

Comment: I'm sending the request from fiddler as shown in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to configure Web API *before* MVC route mappings:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

What I believe is happening is that the framework is trying to map your route to an MVC one. It is assuming that this URI `localhost:8170/api/upload` is referring to an MVC controller called `Api` with an action named `Upload`.

Registering Web API routes before MVC will allow the framework to match routes starting with `api/` to the correct `ApiController`.